# Frustrating issue with NSTask and NSTaskDidTerminateNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

So for the record I have searched for days on this issue. Finally I am at the point where I am  just stuck. I have read the Threading programming guide and followed closely when it talks about NSRunLoops and I think that may be the direction I want to go. Here's the issue:

I have a very simple demo project that consists of just an AppDelegate and a class called TestObj, inside testObj I have

```
@implementation TestObj

-(void)executeTheTaskWithObj:(id)sender {

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"echo hello", nil];
[task setArguments:arguments];

    /* This works but I want to handle the notification in this class, not the senders     class */
//[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:sender    selector:@selector(taskComplete:) name:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification object:task];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(taskComplete:) name:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification object:task];
[task launch];
}

-(void)taskComplete:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"Task Complete");
}
```

This class is called by my appDelegate like so

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
TestObj *myObj = [[TestObj alloc] init];
[myObj executeTheTaskWithObj:self];
}
```

So the problem is the application crashes with "objc_msgSend ()" Breakpoints prove that as soon as I add "self" as the observer, it blows up. I purposely have not multi-threaded this in anyway, it's just a normal call. So my first hunch was maybe I should use an instance of NSRunLoop. So I read the NSRunLoop section of the threading programming guide and it explicitly says that a cocoa application has a runloop started automatically in main. So I should not have to create another one right? I don't want an answer to the question but at least some guidance on how I can solve this. Thank you!

Comment: If you have a crash post the backtrace.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't say crashed. What I mean is it's in a paused state. The debugger just gives Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 13, address=0x0). I have moved the breakpoints around and I can get the task to execute if I set the breakpoint right after [task launch] and it outputs "hello" but pauses right after. The issue I think is that my testObj is being dealloc before it can receive the notification. It has to be something small that I am missing.

Comment: Bad access is a crash.

Comment: Shouldn't this be for OS X? NSTask isn't available for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that myObj is being deallocated after applicationDidFinishLaunching goes out of scope. Create a strong property, myObj, and then it should work properly.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.myObj = [[TestObj alloc] init];
    [self.myObj executeTheTaskWithObj:self];
}
```